# Color gradient for each line/character

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want to make my font have a vertical color gradient without using Javascript, such as [this one](https://chrismcmullen.com/2015/08/30/how-to-make-gradient-text-photoshop-tutorial/).

Text to be applied:

```
<p>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb<br>
  cccccccccccccccc<br>
</p>
```

After some research, I have:

```
[data-component="text-box"] p {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,#9E9F9E,#ffffff);
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
```

However, as I applied the style on `<p>`, the color gradient effect is applied on the whole paragraph, instead of single characters/lines. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF2rZ.jpg))

Is there any way to make it apply on single characters/lines, for **each of them** to have vertical color-gradient? ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu1Au.jpg))

---

Edit: Applying on either single character or single line will be fine, since I want vertical gradient. Vertical gradient for chars/lines are the same.

Comment: You want to assign the gradient to the *background of each character*, or use the gradient on the *character itself*?

Comment: @Raptor Gradient on the character itself, for each of them to be something like black->white from top to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution of the effect you want:

**HTML**

```
<p class="text-gradient">
TaihouKai
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-gradient {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9E9F9E, #ffffff);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Explanation of `background-clip` CSS property (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)):

> The background-clip CSS property sets whether an element's background extends underneath its border box, padding box, or content box.

This property allows the background gradient, image or colour to be "cast" onto the characters themselves.

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mwkt6geo/)

---

**UPDATE** If you want to deal with multiple lines which are separated with line break `<br />`, you can use JavaScript to achieve:

[revised JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/skeq2a1y/1/)

Comment: Would you care to explain how this works? I've never thought to using `background-clip: text`

Comment: Unfortunately, if you add <br> to separate multiple lines in the demo, it is still like my screenshot. I'm thinking of whether line detection would work for this scenario... such as `nth-child()`, probably...?

Comment: @Ibu added the explanation in the answer above.

Comment: @TaihouKai if you want to make the effects work with multiple lines in the same element, you will have to use JS. Let me make a demo. Wait me a sec.

Comment: example updated

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of your CSS gradient text is the actual CSS itself. Check out the basic form of the CSS.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

You can pick any html DOM element and use color gradient font.

Comment: That's incorrect. At least a non-vendor-specific `background-clip` CSS property is missing

Comment: Hello @Raptor, Please check this link. https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/

Comment: Still: https://imgur.com/a/XWPnvlf.

Comment: Also in this CSS tricky, `background-clip` is existing... You can check here also. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Comment: Sorry, your link is not working...

Comment: @DavidSemyonov the tutorial is obviously inaccurate; as mentioned in the tutorial, it's just a "basic form" of the CSS. Some browsers cannot display the effect.

Comment: @DavidSemyonov It's strange... I can access it on my side... Try this? https://ibb.co/QFh9zGc

Comment: I can access the imgur link as well. @TaihouKai can you tell which effect you want? See the comment in your question.

Comment: Yes @TaihouKai, Your link is working...

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite easy solution for this as i wanted to achieve the same effect. I'm more of an amateur regarding css and html and i don't know if this is a no-go but my solution looks as follows:

```css
<h1>
<span class="gradient">Hello </span> 
<br>
<span class="gradient">World</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: It looks like you've not included your CSS in your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).